# REST based URL for complex resource identifier

Tags: api, rest, url

I am trying to construct URL for the REST API that needs to use complex resource identifier

e.g. Get specific Course

```
GET /Courses/{id}
```

where {id} = {TermId}/{SubjectId}/{SectionID}

Is it acceptable to format it as below or there is a better way?

/Courses/{TermId}/{SubjectId}/{SectionID}

Answer (score 0):

It's rather not acceptable, because it introduces confusion to the clients that use the API you provided. Basically `/` (slash) indicates a new resource. In this particular case you have `Courses` resources which has a particular resource with `TermId` which in turn has `SubjectId` and so on. This is not readable and not what client expects. I see two possible solutions here:

1. Use combined key, separated with `-` or other URI-useable sign:

   ```
   GET /Courses/{TermId}-{SubjectId}-{SectionID}
   ```

   Just parse such key on the server side.
2. Use other URI

   ```
   GET /Courses/{courseId}/Terms/{termId}/subjects/{subjectId}/sections/{sectionId}
   ```

There are also other ideas, the one you suggested doesn't seem useable.

Comment: @user1664338 if my answer was helpful please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have two reasonable options:

1. Use a compound key, as @Opal said
2. Use a surrogate key (an arbitrary key with no relation to your three unique constraints)

The advantage to (1) is that the URI is human-hackable - assuming that the user remembers the order to put the values in and what valid values can be. If a significant use case is going to be students using these URIs to find courses online they might like to skip the search step if they have all the relevant information and just punch those values into the URI. If your response type is HTML, this is not unreasonable.

The advantage to (2) is that it's *not* human-hackable - REST is about discovery through hypermedia. If the response type is JSON or XML, humans aren't going to be using these URIs directly.

I would suggest supporting the following endpoints:

```
GET /courses?termId={}&subjectId={}&sectionId={}
// all three parameters are optional. returns all courses that match the
// specified criteria - either a subset of the data or the full course
// data for each result

GET /courses/{courseId}
```